Is there a way to determine if BeforeUnloadEvent is triggered by browser's refresh button or browser's close button?
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
        
        // indicate that exit to Server is called in local storage
        localStorage.setItem('isExitToServerCalled', JSON.stringify(true))
        const test = localStorage.getItem('isExitToServerCalled')
        console.log(`testing condition item: ${test}`);

        // save data that need to be retrieve in the event of refresh and not close
        localStorage.setItem('savedChatID', JSON.stringify(chatID))
        localStorage.setItem('savedCustomUsername', JSON.stringify(customUsername))
        localStorage.setItem('savedUsernameToSend', JSON.stringify(usernameToSend))

        exitToServer();
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    };
}, [usernameToSend]);

given code above, how do i know if i am triggering the BeforeUnloadEvent from browser's refresh button or browser's close button? I want to only call exitToServer() when window's close button is triggered and the rest of the localStorage stuff when refresh button is triggered.
